# Can't run bower or npm through network firewall even with proxy set - ETIMEOUT

Tags: npm, bower, http-proxy

I can't get bower or npm to work though a client's network and I'm not sure if I'm setting up the proxy settings correctly.

I've tried the various suggestions on answers to similar questions and simply nothing works for me. I get the following error:

```
C:\myproj>bower search react
bower retry         Request to http://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/search/react
failed with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 1.7s
bower retry         Request to http://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/search/react
failed with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 3.6s
bower retry         Request to http://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/search/react
failed with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 7.0s
bower retry         Request to http://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/search/react
failed with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 14.6s
```

I can access `http://bower.herokuapp.com` fine though the browser and it serves me the json reply.

my .bowerrc file (used `'\\'` on the domain\user name as it failed to parse it otherwise):

```
{
    "directory": "Content/bower_components",
    "proxy": "http://mydomain\\myuser:mypassword@nnnnn004.claims.local:8080",
    "https-proxy": "http://mydomain\\myuser:mypassword@nnnnn004.claims.local:8080",
    "strict-ssl": false,
    "registry": "http://bower.herokuapp.com"
}
```

for NPM it just hangs:

```
C:\myproj>npm install grunt-cli
npm WARN package.json cl.clientappointment@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json cl.clientappointment@1.0.0 No README data
|
```

my .gitconfig file:

```
[url "http://"]
    insteadOf = git://
[http]
    proxy = http://mydomain\\myuser:mypassword@nnnnn004.claims.local:8080
[https]
    proxy = http://mydomain\\myuser:mypassword@nnnnn004.claims.local:8080
```

my .npmrc file:

```
proxy=http://mydomain\\myuser:mypassword@nnnnn004.claims.local:8080/
https-proxy=http://mydomain\\myuser:mypassword@nnnnn004.claims.local:8080/
strict-ssl=false
```

All works fine if I connect to a different network without firewall.
I'm not sure if I've entered my user name/ password correctly on the proxy string supplied, or if I'm just missing a setting somewhere else.

Comment: Did you check if any of your requests reach the proxy?

Comment: @drorb - no they didn't and I've just found the problem - I didn't escape certain characters in my proxy url e.g. "domain\user" needed to be "domain%5Cuser" in my npm/bower config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was that I didn't escape special characters in my proxy url used by NPM (.npmrc) and Bower (.bowerrc).

i.e.

```
proxy=http://domain\user:password@proxy:8080"
```

needed to be

```
proxy=http://domain%5Cuser:password@proxy:8080"
```